# Choosing title for a section in the curriculum vitae

Tags: cv

I am now applying for lecturer jobs after my masters. And so have made a decent CV. Now I have a confusion on giving the research interests in my CV. I wanted to make 2 sections in CV indicating my basic subject areas and future research interests. What are the suitable titles for these sections in the CV?

Comment: I am from Kerala, India. Here M Tech is the basic qualification for teaching at engineering colleges.

Comment: What do you mean with "basic strong subjects"? And if the position does not even require a PhD, do they actually expect you to do research? If not, why do they care about your research interests?

Comment: Because they wanted people who are willing to do PhD in future rather than to settle with M Tech. Here the atmosphere is very pathetic. Most People do PhD only if they can't escape from it. In private colleges promotions to Associate Professor etc are based on experience and higher degree.

Comment: *Most People do PhD only if they can't escape from it* sounds great ...

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this question. It's on-topic, and the question is concise, clear, and answerable.

Comment: Although my comment is not related to the question, I think it is necessary to point out, in view of the previous comments, that in developing countries it is common for someone to become a lecturer without a PhD or even Master's degree, and to pursue a PhD after some years of lecturing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible heading for your subject areas could be Areas of Specialization or Areas of Expertise. You could use Research Interests for the other part. However, the two are usually combined under one heading. Unless you have the necessary expertise to carry out research in the areas listed under your Research interests, there is no point of listing those.

Normally you would use a separate document called Research Statement to outline your proposal for your upcoming research.